# Have a proplem with ctp. I pass the value from controller. In ctp display Notice (8). How to fix it

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How to fix the Notice (8): Undefined variable: percentage [APP/Template/Cart/checkout.ctp, line 182]

**Controller:**

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $CheckCoupon = $this->Campaign->find('all')
                    ->where(['Campaign.discount_coupon_id' => $this->request->data('coupon')])->first();
            $percentage = $CheckCoupon['discount_percentage'];
```

**Ctp:**

```
<?php 
$actualTotalAmount=$subtotal;
$discountPercent=$percentage;
$discountAmount=($actualTotalAmount)*($discountPercent/100 );
$requestAmount=$discTotalamount=($actualTotalAmount)-$discountAmount;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Controller code doesn't show you actually passing the `$percentage` variable to the view. To pass a variable to a view in CakePHP you need to use `set`:-

```
$this->set('percentage', $percentage);
```

When the variable name is the same as the one you want to set you can also use [PHP's `compact` method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) which creates an array containing variables and their values:-

```
$this->set(compact('percentage'));
```

Comment: I am also use the compact method. $this->set(compact('percentage')); still I have an issue

Comment: Is the `set` method being called? It is difficult to help you with out seeing the code that is actually setting the variable.

Comment: In controller value is printed correctly. Only issue can arrive in ctp. Any guess to find the issue?

Comment: Use this outside of the If condition $this->set('percentage', $percentage); & initilize it before if condition also.